# How do I pickle an object hierarchy, *each object usually its own individual file* so that saving is fast?

Tags: python-3.x, file, serialization, pickle, projects-and-solutions

I want to use pickle, specifically cPickle to serialize my objects' data as a folder of files representing modules, projects, module objects, scene objects, etc.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Thus unpickling will be a little tricky as each parent object stores a reference to child/sibling objects when running but the pickle data of the parent will hold a filepath to the object.

I started with a PathUtil class that all classes inherit, but have been running into issues.  Has anyone solved a similar problem/feature of data file saving / restoring?

The more transparently it works with existing code the better.  For instance, if using a meta class `__call__` will make existing constructor syntax stay the same, that will be a plus.  For example, the static `__call__` will check the pickle file first and load *it* if it exists, while doing a default construction if it doesn't.

Comment: I think `__reduce__` might be used well here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `__getstate__` to write to a new pickle file and return its path, and `__setstate__` to unpickle the file.

```
import pickle, os

DIRNAME = 'path/to/my/pickles/'

class AutoPickleable:

    def __getstate__(self):
        state = dict(self.__dict__)
        path = os.path.join(DIRNAME, str(id(self)))
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(state, f)
        return path

    def __setstate__(self, path):
        with open(path, 'b') as f:
            state = pickle.load(f)
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

Now, each type which should have this special auto-pickleable behavior, should subclass `AutoPickleable`.

When you want to dump the files, you can do `pickle.dumps(obj)` or `copy.deepcopy(obj)` and ignore the result.

Unpickling works as usual (`pickle.load`).  If you want to restore the objects from a file-path (and not from the results of `pickle.dumps`), it is a bit trickier. Let me know if you want it, and I'll add details.  In anycase, if you wrap your `AutoPickleable` object with a "standard" object, and do all pickle operations on that, it should all work.

There are several potential problems with this approach, but for a "clean" case such as the one you describe, it might work.

Some notes:

- There is no way to "dynamically" specify the directory to write to. It has to be globally accessible, and set before the pickling operation
- Probably wouldn't work if several objects keep references the same `AutoPickleable` object, or if you have circular references (in general, pickle handle these cases with no problem)
- There is no code here to clean the directory / delete the files.

Comment: I like how `__getstate__` returns the path.  Since I'm always running into inheritance issues with PyQt5 I will not subclass this but make a member somehow